# Why Does SQL Query of >= '5/1/2018' and <= '5/1/2018' only return rows of 2018-05-01 00:00:00?

Tags: sql, sqldatetime

Ok I should know this after 20+ years of coding and querying databases, but it still doesn't make sense to me.

If I do this:

```
SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE createdate >= '5/1/2018' and createdate <= '5/1/2018'
```

I get:

```
6500061 2018-05-01 00:00:00
6500642 2018-05-01 00:00:00
6505091 2018-05-01 00:00:00
6505453 2018-05-01 00:00:00
6505469 2018-05-01 00:00:00
6505506 2018-05-01 00:00:00
```

But if I do this:

```
SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE createdate >= '5/1/2018 00:00:00' and createdate <= '5/1/2018 23:59:59'
```

I get:

```
6500061 2018-05-01 00:00:00
6500642 2018-05-01 00:00:00
6500652 2018-05-01 11:08:00
6500726 2018-05-01 11:25:00
6500736 2018-05-01 11:27:00
6504776 2018-05-01 15:05:00
6504778 2018-05-01 15:06:00
6505091 2018-05-01 00:00:00
6505371 2018-05-01 17:42:00
6505453 2018-05-01 00:00:00
6505469 2018-05-01 00:00:00
6505506 2018-05-01 00:00:00
6507371 2018-05-02 00:00:00
6508695 2018-05-02 00:00:00
```

Why doesn't SQL return everything that has that date no matter what the time is? Is there another function that I should be putting around my dates so I don't have to put the times in and just look at the dates?

Comment: Because it was designed so, a `datetime` always has a time and `5/1/2018` is the same as `5/1/2018 00:00:00`. But you can also use `>= '5/1/2018' and createdate < '5/2/2018'`

Comment: You can do something like `WHERE CONVERT(DATE, createdate) >= '5/1/2018' and CONVERT(DATE, createdate) <= '5/1/2018'`. Word of warning: If you have indexes on the `createdate` column, they wont be used if you do this.

Comment: As an aside - I would recommend converting the string to a date more explicitly, convert (datetime, '20180501', 112)

Comment: @Andrew `'20180501'` is culture independent. There is no need for CAST/CONVERT at all for date literal in this format.

Comment: Read the first few paragraphs of this: http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes.  Then go back and read them again, they are important, and they answer your question

Comment: @lad2025 - yes, but my habit is to always use explicit casts - the OP's dates were not in the ISO format however, `5/1/2018` and that's less than desirable outside of an explicit cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the times because your data is datetime. You can write a query where you could do what you are asking by casting the createdate as a date.

```
SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE CAST(createdate AS DATE) = '5/1/2018'
```

Comment: Non-sargable query, this will not be good on performance since an index will not support the query properly.

Comment: I agree but giving him an option.

Comment: @Andrew - I've been led to believe that `CAST(<datetime> AS DATE)` *is* Sargable.

Comment: @Andrew - see e.g. [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34047/6381)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, that's a good bit of information I wasn't expecting, thanks.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - looks like it is, although with some caveats, will run some experiments - good info though.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever. I had not seen that either.

Comment: Great information in all of the comments.  We ended up using a statement with the CAST...obviously knowing some of the caveats as mentioned by @Damien_The_Unbeliever